# Bootstrap3 row margin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, margin, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm running into a CSS issue anytime I use Bootstrap 3.
On all the examples supplied on the site, there is a nice 15px margin on the left and right of every row to stop the text running up to the very edge of a viewport/screen.

```
.row {
margin-right: -15px;
margin-left: -15px;
}
```

BUT anytime I download the latest build and work with the released CSS I have content ro the very edge of the viewport. 
I'm looking at my CSS with Developer tools and there's nothign overwriting the twitter CSS so I'm really stumped :-/

Any suggestions?

Comment: Jsfiddle or other example where we can see the problem? Also, are you putting your rows in the container class?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it.

I had a nested Row and didn't realise. I have the content in a CMS and it's mini wrapper template had a duplicate ROW tag which was affecting everything. All fixed now :)